# I am trying to return the avg restaurant rating along with the owners name

Tags: javascript, express, knex.js

I am using knex to create queries for my express server.
I have two tables as follows:

I need to create a join on the two tables through the "owner_id" foreign key. Then I need to return objects containing an "avg" key, representing the average of all ratings by owner. And an "owner_name" key representing the owner of the restaurant. Finally I need to order by owner_name.

Here is what I have in my knex query so far:

```js
function listAverageRatingByOwner() {
 return knex("restaurants as r")
  .join("owners as o", "r.owner_id", "o.owner_id")
  .select("r.rating as avg", "o.owner_name")
  .orderBy("o.owner_name")



}
```

I have also tried:

```js
return knex("restaurants as r")
        .join("owners as o" , "r.owner_id", "o.owner_id")
        .select("r.rating as avg", "o.owner_name")
        .groupBy("o.owner_name")
        .avg("r.rating")
        .orderBy("o.owner_name")
```

and I do get data back from this, but the owners are not grouped together by name with the average corresponding to that specific owner.

Here is what I am getting back :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkgHW.png)

And here is what I am expecting to be returned:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "avg": 3.8200000000000003,
      "owner_name": "Amata Frenzel;"
    },
    {
      "avg": 2.25,
      "owner_name": "Curtice Grollmann"
    },
    {
      "avg": 2.45,
      "owner_name": "Daffy Furzer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help on how to group by owner_name with the avg rating for that owner would be awesome!!

here are my migrations for the two tables:

Owners

[image: 2]

Restaurants

[image: 3]

Comment: Please post your raw `CREATE TABLE` statements instead of a textual description of your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're getting back precisely what you're querying. You've got some restaurants, you've got some owners, you're doing a join between them and pulling the owner name and rating.

You indicate that you're trying to instead group by the name and then calculate an average from each of the ratings values for each restaurant, so you need to explicitly take an average of the ratings field and then provide a groupBy for the owner name as in the following:

```js
return knex("restaurants as r")
        .join("owners as o" , "r.owner_id", "o.owner_id")
        .avg("r.rating as avg")
        .select("avg", "o.owner_name")
        .groupBy("o.owner_name")
        .orderBy("o.owner_name")
```

Your second example was nearly right, but you were discarding the avg aggregate method output when you were selecting directly from the ratings. Here, we do the average aggregate and call that output 'avg', then select on that alias and the owner_name for the result.

Comment: I have tried that way, I have tried numerous ways along the lines of what you suggested and what I included in the post. But once I add .avg or the groupBy clause, it seems to break and no data is returned at all.

Comment: Note that my example is ever so slightly different than your second example in the question. Namely, your select statement isn't referencing the output of the avg method and is instead ignoring it in favor of r.ratings and simply calling it the average.

Comment: Yes I see where you are getting at with that, but I guess what I am wondering is would there be any other way to get the same task done? Because to me what you have seems 100% correct, but it wont work still! I have tried researching other ways to complete this simple query, and can't seem to find any logic that is seeming to work. I thought it was possibly my express middleware for the request that was the problem, but  it does return data when I use the first knex query builder in my example

Comment: Best I can suggest then would be to pull the SQL log off your machine and see what Knex is generating and compare against the SQL it _should_ have used and see if there's something that might have needed further configuration that you're missing.